# How do I handle connecting to a mysql database in a separate class?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

So I have a register and login sequence complete, but I have to connect to the database inside each of these individually. I am trying to use a separate class that I can simply include to be connected to the database. My hopes are that this will simplify future pages that need a db connection and also it will hide my login information to the database. Here is the code; I left the old code in, just 'commented' it out:

**DBconn**

```
class DBconn {

protected $dbname;
protected $dbuser;
protected $dbpassword;
protected $dbhost;

protected $connection;

public function _construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
{
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
    $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
    $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
    $this->dbpass = $dbpass;

    $this->connect();
}

public function getConnection()
{
    return $this->connection;
}

protected function connect()
{
    $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
}




}
?>
```

**dblogin.php**

```
<?php

$db = new DBconn('localhost','phpproject','carl','pdt1848?')

?>
```

**registersecure.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//db classes
require_once "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/db/DBconn.class.php";
require_once "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/db/dblogin.php";

//phpass 
require_once "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php";

if (empty($_POST)){

?>
 <form name="registration" action="registersecure.php" method="POST">
<label for "username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label for "password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br />
<label for "fname">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="fname"/><br />
<label for "lname">Last name: </label> 
<input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
<label for "email">Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email"/><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
}
else{

$form = $_POST;
$username = $form['username'];
$password = $form['password'];
$fname = $form['fname'];
$lname = $form['lname'];
$email = $form['email'];
//$user = 'carl';
//$pass = 'pdt1848?';
$hash_obj = new PasswordHash(8, false);

//check for valid email 
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
   echo "Thank you for using a valid email adress.";
}
else{
   die("Invalid Email, please go back and try again.");
}

// because hashing greatly increases the size of a password, 
// if password is longer than 72 chars it risk DoS attakcs
if (strlen($password)>72){die("Password must be less than 73 characters.");
}

// if the password was hashed correctly it must be longer than 20 char,
// therefore if the hash is less than 20 characters phpass isn't 
$hash = $hash_obj->HashPassword($password);
/*  if (strlen($hash)>=20){
    try{
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpproject', $user, $pass);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PODException $e){
        echo 'Something has gone terribly wrong!';
    }*/
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fname, lname, email)VALUES(:username, :password, :fname, :lname, :email)";
$query = $db->getConnection->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$hash, ':fname'=>$fname,
    ':lname'=>$lname, ':email'=>$email));
//};
if ($result){
    echo "Thanks for registering with us!";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, an error occurred while editing the database. Contact the guy who built this garbage.";
};

};

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have errors in your code.
in DBconn class the constrcut should have double underscores at the beginning `__construct`.

And the next error is in registersecure.php

this
`$query = $db->getConnection->prepare($sql);`
should be
`$query = $db->getConnection()->prepare($sql);`

As a sidenote, this is not the correct way to to get an instance of a connection, either you should close the connection and open it again or you should give a unique name to the connection handler. I personally write my db connection handler class like this:

```
class DBQuery {
  protected static $_connections = array();
  protected $_dbh;

  protected function __construct($dbh = null) {
    if (null !== $dbh) {
      $this->_dbh = $dbh;
    } else {
      $this->_dbh = new PDO(
        sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", DBHOST, DBNAME), 
        DBUSER, DBPASS
      );
    }
    $this->_dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }

  public static function getInstance($config = null) {
    if (null === $config) {
      $hash = "__default__";
      if (!isset(self::$_connections[$hash])) {
        self::$_connections[$hash] = new self();
      }
    } else {
      $hash = sha1(json_encode($config));
      if (!isset(self::$_connections[$hash])) {
        $dbh = new PDO(
          sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", $config->host, $config->name), 
          $config->username, $config->password
        );
        self::$_connections[$hash] = new self($dbh);
      }
    }
    return self::$_connections[$hash];
  }

  public function __call($methodName, $arguments) {
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->_dbh, $methodName), $arguments);
  }

  public function __destruct() {
    $this->_dbh = null; // closes the db connection
  }
}
```

then to get a new instance from any other place you just need to include this in that file

`require_once 'DBQuery.class.php';`

and get a new instance of DBQuery:

`$db = DBQuery::getInstance();`

also you can pass config params like db name, username, password, etc. as an array to connect to a different db on the fly :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made a question. However, I can see that you're addressing your class instance `$db` as if it was the connection, which it isn't. You still need to get the protected connection property with the getter method.

```
$query = $db->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still getting an error however:
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/registersecure.php on line 85

Comment: Can you print the var_dump of $db object? You might be failing to connect at the very start, but it might be failing silently. Also, try and see if changing the require login for an include, just to make sure the DB class is present when you try to instance it.

Comment: Same error still after submitting data unfortunately. Here is result:

object(DBconn)#1 (5) { ["dbname":protected]=> NULL ["dbuser":protected]=> NULL ["dbpassword":protected]=> NULL ["dbhost":protected]=> NULL ["connection":protected]=> NULL }
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/registersecure.php on line 86

Comment: not sure if this is obvious, but this is the line in question:

 $query = $db->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

Comment: See @Aram 's answer. The magic method to construct takes two underscores (your class had only one). The getter is a method, not a property.